# Timestamp Error

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

So there is an error in one of the programs that has been running fine so far in our Production iSeries.

```
     Statement in Error . . . . . . . . . . :   00051900
 RPG Routine  . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   REPROMIS
 Number of Parameters . . . . . . . . . :   005
 Message Type . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   RNX
 Additional Message Info  . . . . . . . :   0114
 Message Data . . . . . . . . . . . . . :
              The year portion of a Date or Timestamp value is not in the correct range.
```

Above is the error. So i understand that the Statement in error is 519 which is this

```
RepromiseMode();
```

So this is just a procedure being called in the iSeries program. As I have mentioned in one of my earlier posts, I am still learning how to read spool files. I have gone through the Job logs, and below is something which I see which might be relevant I thought:

```
Message . . . . :   Data mapping error on member FG205L01.                    
 Cause . . . . . :   A data mapping error occurred on field                    
   Max(FG205F_1.QSRDTE) in record number 0, record format *FIRST, member number
   1, in member FG205L01 file FG205L01 in library FILES, because of error code 
   18. The error code meanings follow: 1 -- There is data in a decimal field   
   that is not valid. 2 -- A significant digit was truncated. 3 -- A floating  
   point value exceeded the maximum representable value. 4 -- A floating point 
   value was less than the minimum representable value. 5 -- A binary floating
```

As the above message says, error code 18 is :

18 -- There is data in a date, time, or timestamp field that is not valid.

Now a bit puzzled on how to move forward. Would this just be a data issue or would this be a program related issue that needs a code change?

Below is the dropbox link where I have placed the spool file.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1jbgqvqn9zaac8g/PD001R_Error.txt?dl=0

Any guidance on how to move forward would be helpful

**

> Update - 1

### **

So as far as the research I did so far taught me, i need to concentrate on the procedure below

```
P RepromiseMode   B

      // ...... Define the procedure interface
     D RepromiseMode   PI

      /Free
       //- Spin the whole file
        CallP  PW012R('INFO':'PD001R0055':ModuleName:' ':
                        ' ':' ':' ':'0':' ':P_COMOrd:P_ItmSeq:
                        ' ':' ':' ':' ':' ');
        If  P_COMOrd = *Blanks;
          Setll (*Loval) PD002F;
          Read  PD002F;
        Else;
          If  P_ItmSeq = *Zeros;
            Setll  (1:'1':P_COMOrd) PD002F;
            Reade  (1:'1':P_COMOrd) PD002F;
          Else;
            Setll  (1:'1':P_COMOrd:%Dec(P_ItmSeq:7:0)) PD002F;
            Reade  (1:'1':P_COMOrd:%Dec(P_ItmSeq:7:0)) PD002F;
          EndIf;
        EndIf;

        Dow  Not %Eof(PD002F);
          wOrdCmp  = E_A2AENB;
          wOrdTyp  = E_A2DCCD;
          wOrdNbr  = E_A2CVNB;
          wItmSeq  = E_A2FCNB;
          wModel   = E_A2MODL;
          hldInvDt = E_A2INVD;
          hldBldDt = E_A2BLDA;
          hldQuaDt = LowDate;
          hldTrnDt = LowDate;
          hldShpDt = LowDate;
          hldPrmDt = LowDate;
          MoreDates = *Off;
GAC03     NextRecord = *Off;

GAC11  //- Check if it is the correct repromise
GAC11     CorrectOrd = *Off;
GAC11     Exec Sql
GAC11       Select '1' into :CorrectOrd
GAC11       From mbc6res0
GAC11       Inner Join pd001f On a1ordy=c6uucc And a1adr0=c6uuca
GAC11       where c6aenb=:wOrdCmp And c6dccd=:wOrdTyp
GAC11             And c6cvnb=:wOrdNbr And a1dvnm=:ModuleName;
GAC11     If  SqlCode > 100;
GAC11       // Actually nothing yet if error then it will not run past here
GAC11     EndIf;

GAC11  //- If the record is for this repromise continue
GAC11     If  CorrectOrd;

       //- Conitune if the PD002F is written
          GetInvDate();
          If  PD002Good;
            Chain (wOrdCmp:wOrdTyp:wOrdNbr:wItmSeq) FG263L02;
            If  %Found(FG263L02);
              Chain (K_FGVIN#) FG203F;
              If  %Found(FG203F);
                If  hldBldDt > *Loval;
                  wInventoryDt = hldBldDt;
                Else;
                  wInventoryDt = %Date();
                EndIf;

       //- Shippable is Yes
                If  V_SHIP = 'Y';
                  wFinGood = 'Y';
                  wSalFmy  = V_SFMLY;
                  wPline   = V_PLINE;
                  wHouse   = V_CHOUSE;
                  ProcRePromise();
                  GetPD002F();

       //- Shippable is NO
                Else;
                  CallP  PW012R('INFO':'PD001R0090':ModuleName:V_CHOUSE:
                                V_VIN:V_MODEL:' ':%Char(V_ORDCMP):V_ORDTYP:
                                V_ORDNBR:'0':' ':' ':' ':' ':' ');
                  LoopDone = *On;
                  wFinGood = 'Y';
                  wSalFmy  = V_SFMLY;
                  wPline   = V_PLINE;
                  wHouse   = V_CHOUSE;
                  ProcRepromise();
                  GetPD002F();
                EndIf;

GAC03  //- Some how there is a valid vin in FG263F but not FG203F then...
GAC03         Else;
GAC04           CallP  PW012R('INFO':'PD001R0210':ModuleName:' ':
GAC04                         K_FGVIN#:' ':' ':%Char(wOrdCmp):wOrdTyp:
GAC04                         wOrdNbr:%Char(wItmSeq):' ':' ':' ':' ':' ');
GAC03           SendEmail = *On;
GAC04           GetPD009F();
              EndIf;

       //- No VIN was found
            Else;
              Chain (wOrdCmp:wOrdtyp:wOrdNbr:wItmSeq) PW019L01;
              If  %Found(PW019L01);

       //- Found in PW019F and it is a Finshed Good VIN
                If  N_B0FASG = 'Y';

       //- End the process the order has not been assigned in the warehouse
       //   yet, but there is a label waiting for assignment all is good.
                  CallP  PW012R('INFO':'PD001R0185':ModuleName:' ':
                              ' ':wModel:' ':%Char(wOrdCmp):wOrdtyp:wOrdNbr:
                              %Char(wItmSeq):' ':' ':' ':' ':' ');

                Else;

       //- Looks for a slot record
                  Chain (wOrdCmp:wOrdtyp:wOrdNbr:wItmSeq) PW014F;
                  If  %Found(PW014F);
                    hldBldDt = P_B5PDAT;
                    MoreDates = *On;

       //- No slot record look for a MO order
                  Else;
                    Chain (wOrdCmp:wOrdtyp:wOrdNbr:wItmSeq) MOMASTLG;
                    If  %Found(MOMASTLG);
                      hldBldDt = %Date(M_ODDTMY:*CYMD);
                      MoreDates = *On;

       //- No MO record send an error email
                    Else;
                      CallP  PW012R('INFO':'PD001R0170':ModuleName:' ':
                              ' ':wModel:' ':%Char(wOrdCmp):wOrdtyp:wOrdNbr:
                              %Char(wItmSeq):' ':' ':' ':' ':' ');
                      SendEmail = *On;
GAC04                 GetPD009F();
                    EndIf;
                  EndIf;
                EndIf;

       //- Error because not in PW019F
              Else;
                CallP  PW012R('INFO':'PD001R0175':ModuleName:' ':
                              ' ':wModel:' ':%Char(wOrdCmp):wOrdtyp:wOrdNbr:
                              %Char(wItmSeq):' ':' ':' ':' ':' ');
                SendEmail = *On;
GAC04           GetPD009F();
              EndIf;

       //- If there needs to be more dates calculate
              If  MoreDates;
                GetSalesFamly();
                P_NumDays = *Zeros;
                wModel = E_A2MODL;
                CallP PD005R(wSalFmy:' ':wModel:P_NumDays);
                DecNumDays = %Dec(P_NumDays:4:0);
                If  DecNumDays = *Hival;
                  CallP  PW012R('INFO':'PD001RE025':ModuleName:' ':
                              ' ':wModel:' ':%Char(wOrdCmp):wOrdtyp:wOrdNbr:
                              %Char(wItmSeq):'PD005R came back with 9999 days':
                              ' ':' ':' ':' ');
                  SendEmail  = *On;
                  NextRecord = *On;
                  GetPD009F();
                Else;
                  Chain (1:'1':wOrdNbr:wItmSeq) MBCDRES0;
                  If  %Found(MBCDRES0);
                    wHouse = B_CDA3CD;
                    Chain (1:'1':wOrdNbr:wItmSeq) MOMASTLG;
                    If  %Found(MOMASTLG);
                      Chain (M_FIWHMY) WHSMST;
                      If  %Found(WHSMST);

       //- Move forward number of days agains work cacendar
                        CYMDDate = %Dec(%Char(hldBldDt:*CYMD0):7:0);
                        Setll (W_CALP:CYMDDate) CALNDRL0;
                        For  j = 0 to DecNumDays;
                          Reade (W_CALP) CALNDRL0;
                          CYMDDate = CDTECA;
                        EndFor;
                      EndIf;

       //- Now update the Quality Date
                      hldBldDt = %Date(CYMDDate:*CYMD);
                      wInventoryDt = hldBldDt;
                      CallP  PW012R('INFO':'PD001R0125':ModuleName:' ':
                                  ' ':wModel:' ':%Char(wOrdCmp):wOrdtyp:wOrdNbr:
                                    %Char(wItmSeq):' ':' ':' ':' ':' ');
                      GetPD002F();
                    EndIf;
GAC05             Else;
GAC05  // DO not send email on this because the file is empty
GAC05               CallP  PW012R('INFO':'PD001R0230':ModuleName:wHouse:
GAC05                           ' ':' ':' ':'0':' ':wOrdNbr:%Char(wItmSeq):
GAC05                           ' ':' ':' ':' ':' ');
GAC05               NextRecord = *On;
                  EndIf;

       //- Get all the dates needed
                  wFinGood = 'N';
                  If  Not NextRecord;
                    QualityDate();
                    CallP  PW012R('INFO':'PD001R0140':ModuleName:' ':' ':wModel:
                              ' ':%Char(wOrdCmp):wOrdtyp:wOrdNbr:%Char(wItmSeq):
                              ' ':' ':' ':' ':' ');
                  EndIf;

                  If  Not NextRecord;
                    TransferDate();
                    CallP  PW012R('INFO':'PD001R0122':ModuleName:' ':' ':wModel:
                              ' ':%Char(wOrdCmp):wOrdtyp:wOrdNbr:%Char(wItmSeq):
                              ' ':' ':' ':' ':' ');
                  EndIf;
                  If  Not NextRecord;
                    ShipWedgeDate();
                    CallP  PW012R('INFO':'PD001R0123':ModuleName:' ':' ':wModel:
                              ' ':%Char(wOrdCmp):wOrdtyp:wOrdNbr:%Char(wItmSeq):
                              ' ':' ':' ':' ':' ');
                    GetPD002F();
                  EndIf;
                EndIf;
              EndIf;
            EndIf;
          EndIf;
GAC11     EndIf;

          If  P_COMOrd = *Blanks;
            Read  PD002F;
          Else;
            If  P_ItmSeq = *Zeros;
              Reade  (1:'1':P_COMOrd) PD002F;
            Else;
              Reade  (1:'1':P_COMOrd:%Dec(P_ItmSeq:7:0)) PD002F;
            EndIf;
          EndIf;
        EndDo;

      /End-Free

     P RepromiseMode   E
```

I am debugging this at the moment but it hasn't crashed so far to pinpoint which **date assignment/date related operation** is causing the issue.

> UPDATE - 2

In the procedure above, a file PD002F is being read. To see the date values of all fields having date data type, I tried to extract this file to Excel using the Export option in CLient access but then the same error was thrown:

```
CWBDB0099 - No more data is available for the stream fetch request

SQL0181 - Value in date, time, or timestamp string not valid.

Cause . . . . . :   The string representation of a date, time or timestamp value is not in the acceptable range.  *N is either the character string constant that is not valid or the column or host variable that contained the string.
```

So is the file corrupt or something?

> UPDATE -3

I tried to extract just one record using RRN < 2 through client access and it worked fine! But when i gave RRN < 3, the same error was thrown. This further strengthens my suspicion that this issue comes up only for particular records.

> Update 4

Here is the offending data from the dump, and the associated date operations:

```
hldInvDt = E_A2INVD; 
hldBldDt = E_A2BLDA; 
hldQuaDt = LowDate; 
hldTrnDt = LowDate; 
hldShpDt = LowDate; 
hldPrmDt = LowDate; 
wInventoryDt = hldBldDt; 
wInventoryDt = %Date(); 
hldBldDt = P_B5PDAT; 
hldBldDt = %Date(M_ODDTMY:*CYMD); 
CYMDDate = %Dec(%Char(hldBldDt:*CYMD0):7:0); 
hldBldDt = %Date(M_ODDTMY:*CYMD); 
CYMDDate = %Dec(%Char(hldBldDt:*CYMD0):7:0); 
CYMDDate = CDTECA; 
hldBldDt = %Date(CYMDDate:*CYMD);

HLDINVDT     DATE(10)    '2017-02-10' 
E_A2INVD     DATE(10)    '2017-02-10' 
LOWDATE      DATE(10)    '0001-01-01' 
HLDQUADT     DATE(10)    '0001-01-01' 
HLDTRNDT     DATE(10)    '0001-01-01' 
HLDSHPDT     DATE(10)    '0001-01-01' 
HLDPRMDT     DATE(10)    '0001-01-01' 
WINVENTORYDT DATE(10)    '2017-02-10' 
P_B5PDAT     DATE(10)    '0017-02-10' 
WINVENTORYDT DATE(10)    '2017-02-10' 
HLDBLDDT     DATE(10)    '0017-02-10' 
M_ODDTMY     PACKED(7,0) 1170210. 
CYMDDATE     ZONED(7,0)  1170210 
CDTECA       PACKED(7,0) 1170126
```

Comment: Are all your date fields defined as date fields, or are some defined as character or numeric fields? Also what date formats are you using? `DATFMT(*ISO)`, `DATFMT(*MDY)` something else? Mixed?

Comment: All the date fields used inside the Procedure (RepromiseMode) that seems to be throwing the error are date fields with ISO format except HighDate which is *USA format

Comment: Data mapping error on member FG205L01. This is the error in the job log when i run this program interactively.

Comment: Do you have `Option(*SRCSTMT)` specified? If so, what line is the error on? If not, add it to `ctl-opt`, and try again.

Comment: Yes this option is included in the Header Spec. As I mentioned in the question, the error is on line 519. Which is basically a call to RepromiseMode Procedure whose code Ive included in the Question.

Comment: Your job log should have more information. Specifically which line in the sub-procedure the job failed at. You may have to press `F1` on the message to see second level text, and then `F9` to see the origin of the message. or just print the job log, and you should see the message trail. I can't get to your dropbox probably because of the firewall here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134691/discussion-between-jmarkmurphy-and-user3311539).

Comment: I added update 4 based on our chat. it gives the information needed to answer the question. Note: debugging is not typically on topic here, but since I have the answer, I will post it.

Comment: Does the error show when running a default RUNQRY against the file or running SELECT * in STRSQL? This might help choose a proper fix.

Comment: This is one strange behaviour I noticed. When running SQL the Date field just showed ++++++ but when RUNQRY was used, '0017-02-01' showed up. Not sure why. And also I could download all records in this file except this one to excel using client access. But when this one was attempted invalid timestamp error had come up

Comment: You can probably use a command such as UPDDTA to update rows that have incorrect dates. Errors are due to using a 'date' format that doesn't match the _data_ format. STRSQL and RUNQRY are using different 'date' formats, so one succeeds and one fails. But they can help locate all incorrect dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple date formats used by IBM i within a date field. They hold different date ranges based on the format of the year portion of the date.

```
Number of Digits in Year               Range of Years
2 (*YMD, *DMY, *MDY, *JUL)             1940 to 2039
3 (*CYMD, *CDMY, *CMDY)                1900 to 2899
4 (*ISO, *USA, *EUR, *JIS, *LONGJUL)   0001 to 9999
```

The error you received indicates that you attempted to move a date with a 4 digit year to a date with a 2 or 3 digit year, and that the year value was out of range for the target date. In this case the specific offender appears to be `hldBldDt` which at the time of the error hade a year of `0017`, and is presumably in `*ISO` format. there are a couple places you do this:

```
CYMDDate = %Dec(%Char(hldBldDt:*CYMD0):7:0);
```

I suspect one of these triggered your error since the year in `hldBldDt` is `0017` and for `*CYMD` that is out of range (the allowable range for `*CYMD` is 1900 - 2899). The question is where did that come from since `hldBldDt` is usually populated using `*CYMD`, and that should keep the dates in range. Looking at the data, I see that `P_B5PDAT` also has a year of `0017`, and that you are assigning `P_B5PDAT` directly to `hldBldDt`. So if this has been running fine, either the value in `P_B5PDAT` has not been used, or somehow you got a bad year in there.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks again for the wonderful support. The year value got corrected by itself through an automated job. So the job will run fine now. However I still do have a number of doubts on reading Spool files and Job logs. Can we have a separate chat or mail to your personal id as the files involved are too big in size for Stack overflow? In case you would like to discuss this as well through SO, im happy to do this.

Comment: I don't think SO is the right place for this conversation. I use http://lists.midrange.com/. There are a lot of folks there that can help out.

Comment: Also, what is going to happen the next time bad data comes through? Does the processing have to wait for the automated job? Can it afford to wait? Is the job going to blow up again? Does that cause any other problems?